# PHP IDE accessible with Orca Screenreader

Tags: php, ide, orca

I am about to migrate from Windows to Linux.

My problem is that I would need an IDE for PHP development that is accessible using Orca screenreader.

As of now, I am using Ubuntu mate with eclipse it is working if I turn off the autocomplete function.

Are there any alternatives? I tried PhpStorm, Atom, but with no luck.

Comment: "but with no luck" .. could you please ellaborate? what was the issue with phpstorm and atom as opposed to eclipse? did the apps at least start did they successfully run the project? what was the issue? also which Orca program are we talking about, this one : https://www.google.com/search?ei=-l7lXLGPMa6djLsPj4yaYA&q=orca+screen+reader&oq=Orca+screen+r&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l5j0i22i30l5.7274.9789..10558...0.0..0.98.1114.13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i10.jodvwtiQxgI ?

Comment: @tatsu Yes this is this program. But then I start IDE orca just doesn't speak. IDE is started, and I was able to create the project using my friend's help. In eclipse if code complission is enabled and orca gets focus on it while I am typing after I finished I can't navigate thru the code before I press ALT+Tab and focus on some other window and then focus back to eclipse.

Comment: Okay so, correct me if I understand wrong, but what you're saying is that your setup with eclipse is functional but sub-optimal, it's hard to work with, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Absolutly.

Comment: What about PhpStorm or Atom? how did they behave?

Comment: They started, but screenreader software didn't speak at all. I couldn't even start a new project without using vision.

Comment: have you seen this? https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8327730 I imagine this means you need to open a bugtracker for both jetbrain apps (intellij, phpstorm...) and Atom. after googling it seems Orca is part of the gnome project and gnome has stopped using bugzilla and is migrating to gitlab for bur reporting, I saw that they do use launchpad in the meantime. I guess your best hope lies with an eclipse plugin of some sort.